# Identify a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Identify $Z_{mn}-$module, $Z_{m}\otimes_{Z_{mn}}Z_{n}$.

We all know that $Z_{m}\otimes_{Z} Z_{n}$ is isomorphic to $Z_{gcd(m,n)}$ over $Z$. I conjecture that $Z_{m}\otimes_{Z_{mn}}Z_{n}$ can be identified with $Z_{\frac{mn}{gcd(m,n)}}$.

In order to prove this, I construct a map $\pi : Z_{mn}\rightarrow Z_{m}\otimes_{Z_{mn}}Z_{n}$ by $\pi(a)=a(1\otimes 1)$. I can prove $gcd(m,n)Z \subset ker(\pi)$. But I don't know how to prove the other direction of inequality.